# Read all data from serial COM (electronic scale) VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I need to read some data from electronic scale connected to COM3

I found a vb.net COM read/write exemple there: 
http://www.innovatic.dk/knowledg/SerialCOM/SerialCOM.htm
direct link for source : http://www.innovatic.dk/knowledg/SerialCOM/MaxiCOM.zip

this is my code :

```
 Dim SpaceCount As Byte = 0 
    Dim LookUpTable As String = "0123456789ABCDEF" 
    Dim RXArray(2047) As Char ' Text buffer. Must be global to be accessible from more threads. 
    Dim RXCnt As Integer      ' Length of text buffer. Must be global too. 

    ' Make a new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort instance, which is able to fire events. 
    Dim WithEvents COMPort As New System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM3", _ 
                                   9600, _ 
                                   Parity.None, _ 
                                   8, _ 
                                   StopBits.One) 

      ' Transmitter subroutine. 
    Private Sub Transmitter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles SendButton.Click 
        COMPort.Open() 
        If COMPort.IsOpen Then 
            Try 
                COMPort.Write(New Byte() {&H5}, 0, 1) 
                COMPort.Write(New Byte() {&H11}, 0, 1) 
                '0x05 0x11 
            Catch ex As Exception 
                MsgBox(ex.Message & "  Check CTS signal or set Flow Control to None.") 
            End Try 

        Else 
            MsgBox("COM port is closed. Please select a COM port") 
        End If 

    End Sub 

    Private Sub Receiver(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles COMPort.DataReceived 
        Dim RXByte As Byte 
        Do 
            '----- Start of communication protocol handling ----------------------------------------------------------- 
            ' The code between the two lines does the communication protocol. In this case, it simply emties the 
            '   receive buffer and converts it to text, but for all practical applications, you must replace this part
            '     with a code, which can collect one entire telegram by searching for the telegram 
            '       delimiter/termination. In case of a simple ASCII protocol, you may just use ReadLine and receive 
            '         in a global string instead of a byte array. 
            ' Because this routine runs on a thread pool thread, it does not block the UI, so if you have any data 
            '   convertion, encryption, expansion, error detection, error correction etc. to do, do it here. 
            RXCnt = 0 
            Do 
                RXByte = COMPort.ReadByte 
                RXArray(RXCnt) = LookUpTable(RXByte >> 4) ' Convert each byte to two hexadecimal characters 
                RXCnt = RXCnt + 1 
                RXArray(RXCnt) = LookUpTable(RXByte And 15) 
                RXCnt = RXCnt + 1 
                RXArray(RXCnt) = " " 
                RXCnt = RXCnt + 1 
                SpaceCount = (SpaceCount + 1) And 31      ' Insert spaces and CRLF for better readability 
                If SpaceCount = 0 Then                    ' Insert CRLF after 32 numbers 
                    RXArray(RXCnt) = Chr(13) ' CR 
                    RXCnt = RXCnt + 1 
                    RXArray(RXCnt) = Chr(10) ' LF 
                    RXCnt = RXCnt + 1 
                Else 
                    If (SpaceCount And 3) = 0 Then        ' Insert two extra spaces for each 4 numbers 
                        RXArray(RXCnt) = " " 
                        RXCnt = RXCnt + 1 
                        RXArray(RXCnt) = " " 
                        RXCnt = RXCnt + 1 
                    End If 
                End If 
            Loop Until (COMPort.BytesToRead = 0) 
            '----- End of communication protocol handling ------------------------------------------------------------- 
            Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf Display)) ' Start "Display" on the UI thread 

        Loop Until (COMPort.BytesToRead = 0)  ' Don't return if more bytes have become available in the meantime 


    End Sub 

    ' Text display routine, which appends the received string to any text in the Received TextBox. 
    Private Sub Display() 
        Received.AppendText(New String(RXArray, 0, RXCnt)) 
    End Sub
```

....................

My problem is:
I send to electronic scale 2 commands (ENQ) 0x05 and DC1 (0x11) to get some results,after that sub Receiver is called automatically multiple times and gets data back pieces by pieces.Because of that I don't know when all data is received to process the results

I've tried to close the port at the and of sub Transmitter but then sub Receiver gives me error for port closed.

I need some help,thanks!

EDIT:

Hi Hans,I've tried this code :

Dim Str As String = ""
        Dim com1 As New System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM3", _
                                  9600, _
                                  Parity.None, _
                                  8, _
                                  StopBits.One)

```
    Try
          com1.ReadTimeout = 10000
        com1.Open()

        com1.Write(New Byte() {&H5}, 0, 1)
        com1.Write(New Byte() {&H11}, 0, 1)
        Do
            Dim Incoming As String = com1.ReadLine
            If Incoming Is Nothing Then
                Exit Do
            Else
                Str &= Incoming & vbCrLf
                RichTextBox.Text = Str
            End If
        Loop
    Catch ex As TimeoutException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        If com1 IsNot Nothing Then com1.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

but I always got :Timeout connection, with code from post#1 I don't got this, thanks!

Comment: Don't pay too much attention to that linked web page.  Read the scale manual instead.  Scales give you a way to detect that you got a full response.  Either by returning a fixed-length response, so you can simply count-off the bytes you got.  Or by sending a special byte to indicate the end of the response.

Comment: HI Hans,I've edit my first post to answer you,thanks!